# How to find both new translations and rotations in a rotated Coordinate system?

Tags: linear-transformations, rigid-transformation

i have 3 translations and 3 rotations known in global coordinate system.

I need to know these 6 movements in a new CS, that is rotated and translated from the global coordinate system: in which I know only the direction of the X axis of the new CS, plus its origin.

How can I convert the known translations and rotations from global CS to the new CS ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know a transformation between the old and the new systems, say $\hat{A}$ such that
$$
\hat{A}\, \vec{v}_{\text{old system}} = \vec{v}_{\text{new system}}
$$
and it has an inverse
$$
\hat{A}^{-1} \vec{v}_{\text{new system}} = \vec{v}_{\text{old system}},
$$
than any transformation $\hat{T}_{\text{old system}}$ in the new system can be presented as
$$
\hat{T}_{\text{new system}} = \hat{A} \hat{T}_{\text{old system}} \hat{A}^{-1}.
$$
If these are given in terms of matrices, you can simply multiply them to convert everything into one matrix.

Intuition behind this is as follows.
Say 
$$
\hat{T}_{\text{old system}} \vec{v}_{\text{old system}} = \vec{u}_{\text{old system}},
$$
and we want certain transformation $\hat{T}_{\text{new system}}$ such that
$$
\hat{T}_{\text{new system}} \vec{v}_{\text{new system}} = \vec{u}_{\text{new system}}.
$$
Consider that
$$
\hat{A} \hat{T}_{\text{old system}} \hat{A}^{-1} \vec{v}_{\text{new system}} =
\hat{A} \hat{T}_{\text{old system}} \vec{v}_{\text{old system}} =
\hat{A} \vec{u}_{\text{old system}} =
\vec{u}_{\text{new system}},
$$
thus $\hat{A} \hat{T}_{\text{old system}} \hat{A}^{-1} = \hat{T}_{\text{new system}}$.

Comment: thank you very much, well, I have only the direction of X axis of the new CS, so how do I calculate the transformation between them ?

Comment: that vector is :  [-115.830   -16.850   113.400] , and I have 6 movements, 3 translations, 3 rotations to convert from old to new CS

Comment: and what is v ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, $\vec{v}$ is any vector from the linear space. Transformations act on vectros in your space. Say, rotation matrix is multiplied by vector and yields a new rotated vector.

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti , I don't fully understand the problem with X. What is the dimensionality of the space you are working with? Are there any restrictions on the transformations between coordinate systems (e.g. new is only rotated with respect to the old one)?

Comment: I have these movements in the global CS : x= 4.6 , y=6.5, z= 7.8 , Rx= 1  , Ry= 2.6, Rz= 0.5 , then , I have the X' : which is the X axis of the new CS, that its direction is defined in the global CS :  [-115.830 -16.850 113.400]. plus : I have the center of the new CS, which is [100,200,500]. with these , I need to know all the new x'y'z'Rx'Ry'Rz'

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti , I'm afraid, there are infiitely many coordinate systems with a given center and X direction in the 3D space. Even assuming you get a new coordinate system with an affine transformation excluding stretches and reflections, you are still able to get infinitely many new systems "rotating around the new X". And without knowing the exact new coordinate system, you can't solve the problem.

Comment: you are so right, shall I please ask your help ? how do you arbitrarily choose a new Y and Z ? and then how would I proceed numerically ?

Comment: also, I don't have points to convert, only these 6 movements

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti , of course, you can define new Y and Z arbitrarily, but wouldn't that lead the overall arbitrary result? The only way to get a meaningful answer is to pose a well-formed question. At the moment you have 2 points in old and new systems -- coordinate center and a point on X axis. If you could define two more to form some sort of pyramid, you could use technique described here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely to recover the transformation matrix.

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti , for example, rotation matrix acts on the whole space, thus you have the whole space of points to convert :)